# Whats the problem with the socketio connection?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

Im having this alot of http petitions (**6k INSIDE LAGGING**) in 1-3 minutes in the console when i receive or send data to a socketio connection.

**Im using node+express in the backend and vue on the front**

[image]
**Backend:**

**app.js**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/app',{useNewUrlParser:true,useFindAndModify:false})
    .then(result =>{
        const server = app.listen(3000)
        const io = require('./sockets/socket').init(server)
              io.on('connection', socket =>{
                //   console.log('client connected')
              })
        if(result){console.log('express & mongo running');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

**I created a io instance to use it on the routes**

```
let io
module.exports = {
    init: httpServer => {
        io = require('socket.io')(httpServer)
        return io;
    },
    getIo:()=>{ 
        if(!io){
            throw new Error('socket io not initialized')
        }
        return io;
    }
}
```

**Then, on the route, depending of the logic, the if,else choose what type socket response do**

```
router.post('/post/voteup',checkAuthentication, async (req,res)=>{
    //some logic
    if(a.length <= 0){
     io.getIo().emit('xxx', {action:'cleanAll'})
    }
    else if(b.length <= 0){
     io.getIo().emit('xxx', {action:'cleanT',datoOne})
    }
    else{                   
     io.getIo().emit('xxx', {action:'cleanX',dataTwo,dataOne,selected})
    }
    res.json({ serverResponse:'success'})
})
```

**In the front (component) (activated with beforeUpdate life cycle hook)**

```
getData(){
    let socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000')
        socket.on('xxx', data => {
        if(data.action === 'cleanX'){
            if(this.selected === data.selected){
                this.ddd = data.dataTwo
            }
            else if(!this.userTeamNickname){
                this.qqq= data.dataOne
            }
        }
        else if(data.action === 'cleanAll'){
            this.ddd= []
            this.qqq= []
        }
        else if(data.action === 'cleanT'){
            this.ddd= data.dataOne
        }
    })            
},
```

**1. What kind of behavior can produce this such error?
2. Is any other most efficient way to do this?**

Comment: What is the client-side function `openSocket()`?

Comment: Is the connection that established the client with the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like socket.io is failing to establish a webSocket connection and has never advanced out of polling.  By default, a socket.io connection starts with http polling and after a bit of negotiation with the server, it attempts to establish a webSocket connection.  If that succeeds, it stops doing the polling and uses only the webSocket connection.  If the the webSocket connection fails, it just keeps doing the polling.

Here are some reasons that can happen:

1. You have a mismatched version of socket.io in client and server.
2. You have some piece of infrastructure (proxy, firewall, load balancer, etc...) in between client and server that is not letting webSocket connections through.
3. You've attached more than one socket.io server handler to the same web server.  You can't do that as the communication will get really messed up as multiple server handlers try to respond to the same client.

As a test, you could force the client to connect only with webSocket (no polling at all to start) and see if the connection fails:

```
let socket = io(yourURL, {transports: ["websocket"]})'
socket.on('connect', () => {console.log("connected"});
socket.on('connect_error', (e) => {console.log("connect error: ", e});
socket.on('connect_timeout', (e) => {console.log("connect timeout: ", e});
```

Comment: hello @jfriend00 
1. both client (socksocket.io-client) - server (socket.io) versions are 2.3.0 
2. Im not using anything like nginx etc, just express
Note: Ill try {transports: ["websocket"]
Note2: Is a good practice to create socket inside routes?

Comment: @AlexHunter - I didn't realize you were creating socket.io server inside a route.  That will not work as you will get multiple socket.io handlers attached to the same server and will will get a connection mess.  If you're doing that, that could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Hello, I added the method you just told me "transport websocket" and it work perfect... But as I was saying, this is good practice? Can you show a good and maybe best practice to this?

Comment: @AlexHunter - The only reason not to specify the webSocket transport is to allow support for really old browsers.  It probably means that something is wrong in your configuration elsewhere, but if setting the transports works, then you're probably fine.

Comment: i think so... but i really need to create this component in the best way possible, because it will handle alot of users (petitions), so in this case i need "the best way to code it", do you know any good course of socketio?

Comment: @AlexHunter - I don't know any good courses on socket.io.  If you watch every question about  `javascript`, `socket.io` and `javascript`, `webSocket` tags here on stackoverflow, you will learn a lot.